# Как реализовать список меток?

Tags: recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

Пытаюсь сделать список - сетку из меток (как в нашем сообществе, в овалах друг за другом, если места не хватает, то переходить на другой ряд), создал адаптер `RecyclerView` и не знаю какой `LayoutManager` использовать, ведь он должен вставлять `View` дальше, но если места не хватает, то переходить на другую строку. `GridLayoutManager` для этого не подойдет, ему надо передавать фиксированное количество столбцов. Нашел какой-то `GridAutofutLayoutManager`, но он не подходит тоже, ведь ему надо передать ширину столбца. Не то все, ведь тот `LayoutManager`, который мне нужен, вообще не нуждается ни в чем, кроме контекста. Передаю треть ширины экрана, но это не то.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может, вообще, через `Spannable` можно? Метки должны быть кликабельны. Помогите, пожалуйста, полдня мучаюсь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл библиотеку > https://github.com/nex3z/FlowLayout

А то что ниже - зря:

Преодолев кучу грабель, сделал это через `Spannable`, вооружился библиотекой [Spanny](https://github.com/binaryfork/Spanny).

Итак, тэг `TextView`

```
<TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/marks_tv"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"/>
```

Код

```
List<String> marks = i.getStringArrayListExtra("marks");
    Spanny span = new Spanny();
    span.append("Метки:", new RoundedBackgroundSpan(ctx, Color.TRANSPARENT, Color.BLACK, category.getTextSize(), 0));
    int spanCount = 0;
    for (String mark : marks){
        String marked = mark.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "-");
        if(!marked.equals(category.getText())){
        span = span.append("   ");
        span = span.append(marked, new RoundedBackgroundSpan(ctx, Color.parseColor("#000000"), Color.parseColor("#ffffff"), category.getTextSize(), 10));
        spanCount++;
    }
    }
    if(spanCount == 0){
        marks_tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
    marks_tv.append(span);
        marks_tv.post(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run ()
                {
                    marks_tv.setMinimumHeight(marks_tv.getHeight() + Utils.dpToPx(ctx, 6));
                }
    });
}
```

Кастомный `RoundedBackgroundSpan`

```
public class RoundedBackgroundSpan extends ReplacementSpan {

private static final int CORNER_RADIUS = 20;

private float PADDING_X;
private float PADDING_Y;

private float MAGIC_NUMBER;

private int mBackgroundColor;
private int mTextColor;
private float mTextSize;

private Context ctx;

public RoundedBackgroundSpan(Context ctx, int backgroundColor, int textColor, float textSize, int paddingX) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
    mBackgroundColor = backgroundColor;
    mTextColor = textColor;
    mTextSize = textSize;
    PADDING_X = Utils.dpToPx(ctx, paddingX);
    PADDING_Y = Utils.dpToPx(ctx, 2);
    MAGIC_NUMBER = Utils.dpToPx(ctx, 2);
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, CharSequence text, int start, int end, float x, int top, int y, int bottom, Paint paint) {
    paint = new Paint(paint);
    paint.setTextSize(mTextSize);
    paint.setColor(mBackgroundColor);
    float textHeightWrapping = Utils.dpToPx(ctx, 2);
    float tagBottom = top + textHeightWrapping + PADDING_Y + mTextSize + PADDING_Y + textHeightWrapping;
    float tagRight = x + getTagWidth(text, start, end, paint);
    RectF rect = new RectF(x, top, tagRight, tagBottom);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, CORNER_RADIUS, CORNER_RADIUS, paint);
    paint.setColor(mTextColor);
    canvas.drawText(text, start, end, x + PADDING_X, tagBottom - PADDING_Y - textHeightWrapping - MAGIC_NUMBER, paint);
}

private int getTagWidth(CharSequence text, int start, int end, Paint paint) {
    return Math.round(PADDING_X + paint.measureText(text.subSequence(start, end).toString()) + PADDING_X);
}

@Override
public int getSize(Paint paint, CharSequence text, int start, int end, Paint.FontMetricsInt fm) {
    paint = new Paint(paint); 
    paint.setTextSize(mTextSize);
    return getTagWidth(text, start, end, paint);
}
}
```

Если что-то непонятно, пишите - отвечу.

Скриншоты

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]